Can't see embedded power automate images in Outlook App for iOS currently
I can't see embedded power automate images in Outlook App for iOS currently. There is no way to download them. The links on them work, but the images don't show. It's just a box outline with a question mark. I'm using HTML and CSS. This works fine on the old outlook desktop, gmail app for iOS and gmail for windows desktop.
Outlook App iOS - Image 1
Outlook App iOS - Image 2
I tried the above attached photos using CSS and HTML, but they don't display on Outlook for iOS App as of today's date and also for the new outlook for desktop app.
Help!
Thanks!
